# finding exact variable in tho list on prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I think this question must be solved :))

```
concert(dtatu, [jack, volker, rachel]).

concert(tmegadeth, [volker, rachel]).

concert(ssoad, [kurt, rachel]).

concert(trbeyonce, [kurt,jack,volker]).
```

I want to implement the predicate audiance(L1, L2). returns the list of all people(L2) who have watched all the concerts in L1. The lists L1 and L2 must not contain any duplicates.

```
audiance([tatu,beyonce],X). returns X=[jack,volker]

audiance(X,[volker,rachel]). returns X=[tatu,megadeth]

audiance(X,[kurt,volker,rachel])

audiance([tatu, beyonce],[jack, volker]) returns true

audiance(X,Y). returns X=[tatu], Y=[jack, volker, rachel]; X=[megadeth, soad], Y=[rachel];...
```

this is very hard for me. But I think If I know how to do it, I would not have any problem with prolog :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid duplication, first you can extract all performers from the clause database and find corresponding audiences for a specific set of performers. A solution could be as follows:

```
subset([], []).
subset(Xs, [_|Ys]) :- subset(Xs, Ys).
subset([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- subset(Xs, Ys).

allPerformers(Ts) :- findall(T, concert(T, _), Ts).
performers(T) :- allPerformers(Ts), subset(T, Ts).

audience1([T], L) :- concert(T, L).
audience1([T|Ts], L) :- concert(T, L0), audience1(Ts, L1), intersection(L0, L1, L).

audience(X, Y) :- performers(X), audience1(X, Y).
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code is quite right. And gave me lots of ways how to figure a question out. However I think there a problem. You are making subsets of people like [jack], [jack, volker] etc. However it can be give like audience(X,[volker, jack]). Therefore it cannot find the list because of the order. How can I fix it??

Comment: You could update the last clause to add the permutation/2 predicate for the variable Y, it would solve that problem.

Comment: I see what you mean. But this time, program is trying every permutation. :( I could not solve unfortunatelly :((